# rrestrict the direct url file name with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

hello I'm new to javascript

I just created my first website with 2 pages, eg page1.html and page2.html

if the user is not logged in (page1.html) still they can have access to other pages (page2.html) through URL

I want to stop url access with javascript

Please suggest me how to do it

Comment: To do this in a secure manner you need to put your authentication & authorisation logic on the server side. While it's possible to recreate the behaviour in client side JS, it will not be secure in any meaningful way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.